# How can you a access a superclass from inside a subclass in different a file?

Tags: python, import, python-import, subclass

I'm trying to create an instance of a subclass in a script called main.py. The subclass and its associated superclass each live in separate files in a subdirectory. The file structure is as follows:

- main.py
- protocols

  - protocol.py (inside is a superclass named protocol)
  - MovingBar.py (inside is a subclass named MovingBar)

In main.py I can load the protocol superclass using `from protocols.protocol import protocol` Using this approach I can generate an instance of the superclass without issue.

However, when I next try to load the MovingBar subclass using `from protocols.MovingBar import MovingBar` I get the following error

NameError: name 'protocol' is not defined

Presumably, this is because I have a reference to protocol in the class def of MovingBar as follows:

```
class MovingBar(protocol):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

I'm not sure why python recognizes a reference to protocol in the main.py file, but not when it's in the MovingBar file. Is there a way to import protocol such that it can be seen when I'm subsequently importing MovingBar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `from protocol import protocol` in your `MovingBar.py`.  Modules do not inherit the global environment of their callers.